# Calculating powers of 2, prints out 0 every time

Tags: c

Here's my code:

```
int foo() {
  int a = 1;
  while(1) {
    a *=  2;
    printf("a = %d\n", a);
  }
  return a;
}


int main(void) {
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

It just keeps printing out "a = 0". I'm confused! Am I missing something really simple?

Comment: It works fine for me ([Link](https://ideone.com/xy4hay))

Comment: WTF is `while (1)` you intentionally never exit from the loop?

Comment: @iharob I doubt this is the entire actual program. It's probably a simple example designed to show only what the problem is, just like you're supposed to post on SO.

Comment: Also to print powers of two you should learn the `<<` operator.

Comment: why didn't the OP make the example a simple `for (...)` this bothers me, because i've seen it in very wierd situations where someone deliberately uses `while (1)`... And also, with a simple for like `for (i = 0 ; i < 31 ; i++)` the problem wouldn't happen, would it?

Comment: Very similar question in Java: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24173463/1402846

Answer (score 6):

It overflows to zero, and stays there.